# How to Convert Horizontal Rows into Fixed width Vertical Rows

Tags: microsoft-excel

[image]

I want to Split the data of fixed 4 cells into its row

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you explain a little more, and tell us the research you have done and what you have tried yourself to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to paste them with the transpose option as shown below:

[image]

- Select your data (as you did in your image)
- Copy them
- Paste Special (below the standard Paste method) - and use the `Transpose (T)` method.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are trying to find a formula that converts the row and column of the current cell into coordinates in the source table.

Try writing the formula

`=OFFSET($A$1;MOD(ROW()-1;3);INT((ROW()-4)/3)*4+COLUMN()+3)`

in A4 and stretch it to the right 4 columns and down as much as you need.